# How to join local computer to azure virtual server domain?

Tags: virtual-machines, azure, virtual-network, microsoft-virtual-server

Scenario: I want to migrate my servers to cloud and retire all local servers such as DC and file server. At the same time, I wish to control the network traffic to limit the clients access to Internet resources. I am not sure retiring the all local servers is something right to do and how to do.

What I have done:

1. Site-to-Site VPN connection with Dell Sonicwall TZ205 to VNet. (I followed the route-based VPN in [this document](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fsupport.software.dell.com%2Fdownload%2Fdownloads%3Fid%3D5343958&ei=ykGhVIK6GISWuASU6oHQBw&usg=AFQjCNGGS6fsuK6IHAWyQgZi5fey4xhfKg&bvm=bv.82001339,d.c2E&cad=rja))
2. Created a VM in the VNet. (I can ping the VM from computers connected to TZ205)
3. Installed active directory and configured the domain forest.

What I need to do:

1. How to join the local computers to the virtual server domain controller with S2S and P2S VPN. (Some Internet resources mentioned I need to install Connect agent in order to do this)

Extra questions:

1. Is it possible to request the clients to provide account credentials before the point-to-site VPN to VNet is established ?
2. How do I configure the TZ205 VPN router to send all the Internet traffic to the VNet instead of the ISP gateway? The computers connected to TZ205 firewall router public IP address doesn't change to the VNet gateway IP.

Thanks for your time reading my questions. It will be helpful if you can provide me some useful links or ideas.

Comment: I shudder to think of your egress data charges when moving a file server to Azure - consider OneDrive for Business instead. Also, you probably dont want to route *all* internet-bound traffic to Azure. That's another great way to incur a large egress traffic bill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question 1:

With S2S VPN the routing should be able to do the job correctly. Make sure the remote computer got the remote DC as the only DNS's server.

With P2S VPN you need a client that can connect before the login. Thus you join the computer in the domain after establishing the vpn, and in the reboot after you can loging before the domain logon. I know that the cisco vpn client allow a pre-login vpn login.

Extra 1: Like I state earlier, you better make the vpn login before, so the computer will not use the cached login.

Extra 2: I don't recommand that configuration. That will put more stress over your VPN tunnel and your cloud site ISP.